# What is a powerful, lightweight text editor with intuitive GUI/functionality?

Tags: editor

To date in my programming career I've been using gedit for everything, but I am beginning to feel it isn't powerful enough.

However, I find that EMACS and VIM are too annoying because of the massive number of unintuitive keyboard shortcuts, and the inability to do simple things like click and drag to select things, ctrl+c, ctrl+v, etc. Also, any editor with different modes is really annoying to me.

On the other hand, gedit lacks a lot of the powerful things VIM and EMACS seem to be able to do. I have seen my coworkers do things like pop open a list of all files containing a certain regular expression to open, or compile and execute a selected block of code in a single stroke.

I've installed all the gedit plugins I can find, but it's hard to customize them to the extent I want to, and a lot of them just suck. For example, ctrl-alt-o for quick open seems to simply provide a short list of recently opened files. And the integrated command line plugin is pretty awful. The autocomplete plugin is decent, but it would be much better if it could show me a list of all the available methods of an object the way ipython does.

Is there an editor out there that functions more or less like normal text editors, but with the customizability and support you get from VIM/EMACS? Or is there a build for VIM/EMACS out there that feels like a normal editor without all the confusing modes or need for encyclopedic knowledge of keyboard shortcuts?

I mostly program in python, coffeescript, java, and am about to start using C++ a lot, plus I occasionally do things in other languages, so functionality across multiple languages is a must.

Comment: This kind of question is considered "Not constructive" because it does not have a single objective answer.

Comment: That being said, try Sublime2.

Comment: wow, sublime2 looks really cool-- I'll have to try it out. It isn't free though?

Comment: It's nagware (Popups a dialog every now and then)

Answer (score 0):

A coworker of mine likes Geany and he uses it for C and Javascript development. I don't know anything about except that it's more powerful than Gedit, but doesn't have the same feel as VIM/EMACS.

You can also try `behave mswin` in VIM: https://superuser.com/questions/10588/how-to-make-cut-copy-paste-in-gvim-on-ubuntu-work-with-ctrlx-ctrlc-ctrlv. I don't like it, but another coworker does. It changes the whole feel of VIM, which might be what you want.

I would just recommend picking a more powerful editor and get used to it. VIM/EMACS are good editors, but trying to make them behave other than they were designed may cause problems down the line (especially when looking for help).

Comment: "trying to make them behave other than they were designed may cause problems down the line (especially when looking for help)."
Yeah, I definitely do have this fear, but I will check out behave mswin

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend taking the time to learn something like Vim. You might find it easier than you think.

Cream is a version of Vim modified to have an easier user interface.
http://cream.sourceforge.net/